# To change SVG image styles/effects on click, through code without rendering new SVG image

Tags: javascript, css, html, angular, svg

[image: Image to be changed on click of image]

[image: Default image rendered on page load]

```html
<div id="svgDiv">
<img src="SVG_90_default.svg"/>
</div>
```

Here, in a div, I am directly rendering SVG image in img tag, 'SVG_90_default.svg'. But, on click of this image, its color and its text should change to white color as in attached image. I don't want to load that other image on click, as it affects performance. So, how can we change the color of embedded SVG image through code here?

-------SVG_90_default.svg-----

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 118.46 116"><defs><style>.cls-1,.cls-3{fill:none;stroke-miterlimit:10;}.cls-1{stroke:#6e7b9f;opacity:0.5;}.cls-2,.cls-4{fill:#36c;}.cls-3{stroke:#36c;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-width:2px;}.cls-4{font-size:14.42px;font-family:Calibri, Calibri;}</style></defs><title>90S_Default</title><g id="Layer_2" data-name="Layer 2"><g id="Collimator_Change_Default" data-name="Collimator Change Default"><g id="_90S_Default" data-name="90S_Default"><rect class="cls-1" x="1.73" y="0.5" width="115" height="115" rx="2" ry="2"/><rect class="cls-2" x="44.78" y="21" width="28.9" height="10.84" rx="2" ry="2"/><rect class="cls-2" x="22.02" y="40.78" width="29.77" height="11.16" rx="2" ry="2" transform="translate(-9.46 83.27) rotate(-90)"/><path class="cls-3" d="M39.13,65.71A27.9,27.9,0,1,0,78.83,26.5"/><text class="cls-4" transform="translate(51.92 101.07)">90</text></g></g></g></svg>
```

---------------SVG_90_OnClick.svg-----------------------

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 116 116"><defs><style>.cls-1{fill:#36c;stroke:#36c;}.cls-1,.cls-3{stroke-miterlimit:10;}.cls-2,.cls-4{fill:#f2f2fc;}.cls-3{fill:none;stroke:#f2f2fc;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-width:2px;}.cls-4{font-size:14px;font-family:Calibri, Calibri;}</style></defs><title>90S_Selected</title><g id="Layer_2" data-name="Layer 2"><g id="Collimator_Change_Selected" data-name="Collimator Change_Selected"><g id="_90S_Selected" data-name="90S_Selected"><rect class="cls-1" x="0.5" y="0.5" width="115" height="115" rx="2" ry="2"/><rect class="cls-2" x="43.55" y="21" width="28.9" height="10.84" rx="2" ry="2"/><rect class="cls-2" x="21.87" y="42.67" width="28.9" height="10.84" rx="2" ry="2" transform="translate(-11.76 84.41) rotate(-90)"/><path class="cls-3" d="M38.49,66.87A27.09,27.09,0,1,0,77,28.8"/><text class="cls-4" transform="translate(50.9 101.2)">90</text></g></g></g></svg>
```

Comment: You could convert the image to a data URI and then rewrite the data URI onclick so that it has the new colour.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible with `img` tag. You will need to use a `svg` element here.

You can use `:focus` pseudo class to change the `fill` and `stroke` property of svg on click. You will need to use `tabindex` to `:focus` work

```css
* {
  outline: none;
}

svg:focus .cls-1 {
  fill: #3366cc;
}

svg:focus .cls-2,
svg:focus .cls-4 {
  fill: white;
}

svg:focus .cls-3 {
  stroke: white;
}
```

```html
<svg tabindex="1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 118.46 116" width="100" height="100"><defs><style>.cls-1,.cls-3{fill:none;stroke-miterlimit:10;}.cls-1{stroke:#6e7b9f;}.cls-2,.cls-4{fill:#36c;}.cls-3{stroke:#36c;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-width:2px;}.cls-4{font-size:14.42px;font-family:Calibri, Calibri;}</style></defs><title>90S_Default</title><g id="Layer_2" data-name="Layer 2"><g id="Collimator_Change_Default" data-name="Collimator Change Default"><g id="_90S_Default" data-name="90S_Default"><rect class="cls-1" x="1.73" y="0.5" width="115" height="115" rx="2" ry="2"/><rect class="cls-2" x="44.78" y="21" width="28.9" height="10.84" rx="2" ry="2"/><rect class="cls-2" x="22.02" y="40.78" width="29.77" height="11.16" rx="2" ry="2" transform="translate(-9.46 83.27) rotate(-90)"/><path class="cls-3" d="M39.13,65.71A27.9,27.9,0,1,0,78.83,26.5"/><text class="cls-4" transform="translate(51.92 101.07)">90</text></g></g></g></svg>
```

Comment: But, I need to do it with image tag only. Not by using svg element. Is there any solution for it.

Comment: @EatingCode you meen in html instead `svg` you want `img`?

Comment: @EatingCode what is the problem using svg. `svg` loaded faster than the `img` tag

Comment: @Bhuwan our requirement is like that, as there are many of the svg images in a page to be loaded, and images may change in future. We should be able to render svg images directly and not writing code for changed svgs every time

Comment: @Bhuwan If we give that focus style effect as part of the SVG itself i.e. if we include those focus css styles as part of SVG element itself, even though if we render image in <img> or <iframe> or <object> tag, click effect works.... Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

In case with single solid color images you can use css filter (svg just as example, will work with img tag also):

```css
#svgDiv svg,
#svgDiv img {
  width: 100px;
}

#svgDiv:hover {
  background: #36c;
}

#svgDiv:hover svg,
#svgDiv:hover img {
  filter: brightness(100);
}
```

```html
<div id="svgDiv">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 118.46 116"><defs><style>.cls-1,.cls-3{fill:none;stroke-miterlimit:10;}.cls-1{stroke:#6e7b9f;opacity:0.5;}.cls-2,.cls-4{fill:#36c;}.cls-3{stroke:#36c;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-width:2px;}.cls-4{font-size:14.42px;font-family:Calibri, Calibri;}</style></defs><title>90S_Default</title><g id="Layer_2" data-name="Layer 2"><g id="Collimator_Change_Default" data-name="Collimator Change Default"><g id="_90S_Default" data-name="90S_Default"><rect class="cls-1" x="1.73" y="0.5" width="115" height="115" rx="2" ry="2"/><rect class="cls-2" x="44.78" y="21" width="28.9" height="10.84" rx="2" ry="2"/><rect class="cls-2" x="22.02" y="40.78" width="29.77" height="11.16" rx="2" ry="2" transform="translate(-9.46 83.27) rotate(-90)"/><path class="cls-3" d="M39.13,65.71A27.9,27.9,0,1,0,78.83,26.5"/><text class="cls-4" transform="translate(51.92 101.07)">90</text></g></g></g></svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.